# Text View set visibility gone not working

Tags: java, android, textview, visibility

I have a recipe app which displays quantities of ingredients, when a textview row is not used for an ingredient i set the corresponding value to 0 then in a setText method I set all textviews with value of 0 to setVisbility(View.GONE but they are still there. Note the rows of 0g below. Any ideas?

[image: Bakers Pride ©ollygrov]

Ok so I set each ingredient like so.

```
        A = 150;
        B = 3;
        C = 1;
        D = 3;
        E = 90;
        F = (A+B+C+D+E+F);
        G = 0;
        H = 0;
        I = 0;
        J = 0;

        a = "French Flour:";
        b = "Salt:";
        c = "Improver:";
        d = "Yeast:";
        e = "Water:";
        f = "Total Weight:";
        g = "";
        h = "";
        i = "";
        j = "";
```

G, H, I and J aren't needed so I set them to 0.
Then I have a method which does this at the end of my onCreate, but to each (unused) row:

if (G == 0) {

```
        A6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

EDIT: Got the problem down to a specific point, I noticed one of the views actually did disappear through View.GONE. Commented the command out and it came back. Now I'm thinking maybe there is a set amount of textViews you can have before it all starts messing up. I do have 40 in total for all the ingredients, plus more with the layout. Going to see what I can do with a TableLayout. If anyone has some better suggestions...

Comment: mind if you get naked and show us some code? it'll be hard to help otherwise :)

Comment: What is A6? can you make sure this line executed?

Comment: try to print a debug line inside the if and see if your code will execute that part of code

Comment: A6 is the TextView. Ok I'll get back to you

Comment: I've tried but I can't figure out how to debug properly. I'm quite new and never had to before. had a look on eclipse debugger but it just confused me. Try / catch method or what?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I gave up on the setVisibility() method. What could have been an easy fix - I decided to recreate the entire section using Double and String ArrayLists, for loops and new TextViews.. Now it keeps the layout tidy because the activity is only generating the required amount of TextViews, instead of deleting when necessary. Sorry to anyone looking for the solution to the original question.

Comment: See *[setVisibility(View.GONE) not working for textview](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28467157/192373)*. Maybe your TextView had focus, too?