# setVisibility(View.GONE) not working for textview

Tags: android

I am retrieving and displaying values from a database but all queries don't return the same number of columns so I have to hide the ones that are not required.
java:

```
package com.example.testback;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Stations extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    String lat,lng,marker;
    Spinner s1, s2;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stations);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Display display =getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int height = display.getHeight();
        int top=(int) (height/5.4);
        LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearL2);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                   LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(0, top,0,0);
        l.setLayoutParams(lp);

        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.countries);
        s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.region);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.Countries, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String name= extras.getString("name");
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(
                this.getApplicationContext());
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        // Open the database
        try {

            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Get the readable version
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cur;
        cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM REGIONS WHERE _id='"+name+"';", null);
        int i = 0;
        cur.moveToFirst();
        TextView v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
        v.setText(cur.getString(1));
        int index;

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("ph1");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ph1);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tit_ph1);
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ph1);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tit_ph1);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("ph2");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ph2);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tit_ph2);
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ph2);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tit_ph2);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("fax");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fax);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tit_fax);
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fax);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tit_fax);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("email1");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.email1);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.email1);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("email2");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.email2);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.email2);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("dom_ph1");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dom_ph1);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dom_ph1);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("dom_ph2");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dom_ph2);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dom_ph2);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("dom_fax");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dom_fax);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dom_fax);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("dom_email1");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dom_email1);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dom_email1);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("dom_email2");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dom_email2);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dom_email2);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("int_ph1");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.int_ph1);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.int_ph1);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("int_ph2");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.int_ph2);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.int_ph2);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("int_fax");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.int_fax);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.int_fax);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("int_email1");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.int_email1);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.int_email1);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("int_email2");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.int_email2);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.int_email2);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("cargo_ph1");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cargo_ph1);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cargo_ph1);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("cargo_ph2");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cargo_ph2);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cargo_ph2);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("cargo_fax");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cargo_fax);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cargo_fax);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("cargo_email1");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cargo_email1);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cargo_email1);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndex("cargo_email2");
        if(index!=-1){
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cargo_email2);
            v.setText(cur.getString(index));
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cargo_email2);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        index=cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("loc_lat");
        lat=cur.getString(index);
        index=cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("loc_long");
        lng=cur.getString(index);
        index=cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("marker");
        marker=cur.getString(index);
        /*while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
            //list.add(cur.getString(0));
            cur.moveToNext();
        }*/

        cur.moveToPosition(0);

        // Close
        myDbHelper.close();
    }
    public void go(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(Stations.this, Map.class);
        i.putExtra("lat",lat);
        i.putExtra("long",lng);
        i.putExtra("marker",marker);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (s1.getSelectedItem().equals("India")) {
            list.add("Select Station");
            DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(
                    this.getApplicationContext());
            myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

            try {
                myDbHelper.createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new Error("Unable to create database");
            }

            // Open the database
            try {

                myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                sqle.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Get the readable version
            SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cur;
            cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM REGIONS ORDER BY _id ASC;", null);
            int i = 0;
            cur.moveToFirst();
            while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
                list.add(cur.getString(0));
                cur.moveToNext();
            }

            cur.moveToPosition(0);

            // Close
            myDbHelper.close();
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        } else if (s1.getSelectedItem().equals("SAARC Countries")) {
            list.add("Select Station");
            list.add("Chittagong");
            list.add("Colombo");
            list.add("Dhaka");
            list.add("Kabul");
            list.add("Kathmandu");
            list.add("Male");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        } else if (s1.getSelectedItem().equals("Russia")) {
            list.add("Moscow");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        } else if (s1.getSelectedItem().equals("USA and Canada")) {
            list.add("Select Station");

            list.add("Chicago");
            list.add("Los Angeles");
            list.add("New York");
            list.add("Toronto");
            list.add("Washington DC");
            list.add("Newark Airport (EWR)");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        } else if (s1.getSelectedItem().equals("Southeast Asia, Australia")) {
            list.add("Select Station");
            list.add("Bangkok");
            list.add("Hongkong");
            list.add("Jatarka");
            list.add("Melbourne");
            list.add("Sydney");
            list.add("Yangon");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        } else if (s1.getSelectedItem().equals("Gulf and Middle East")) {
            list.add("Select Station");
            list.add("Bahrain");
            list.add("Beirut");
            list.add("Cairo");
            list.add("Dubai");
            list.add("Muscat");
            list.add("Tehran");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }

        else if (s1.getSelectedItem().equals("UK and Europe")) {
            list.add("Select Station");

            list.add("Amsterdam");
            list.add("Frankfurt");
            list.add("London");
            list.add("Madrid");
            list.add("Zurich");
            list.add("Paris");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        } else if (s1.getSelectedItem().equals("Far East")) {
            list.add("Select Station");

            list.add("Osaka");
            list.add("Seoul");
            list.add("Tokyo");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }
        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                if (s2.getSelectedItem().toString() != "Select Station") {
                    String s = s2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Stations.this, Stations.class);
                    i.putExtra("name", s);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The xml for that element is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tit_fax"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".4"
            android:text="FAX"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fax"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".6"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:text=" " />
</LinearLayout>
```

But it is still visible when it should have been gone

Comment: Then index is always -1. Have you checked its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
v=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fax);
v1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tit_fax);
```

keep this in globally then its work,no need to use `View.VISIBLE`,Keep the variable unique

Don't use this in your XML,because it get confused

```
android:visibility="visible"
```

Comment: what does keep this in globally mean

Comment: I have checked the index value does change

Comment: android:visibility="visible" remove this from textview XML

Comment: I removed that didn't change anything

Comment: you used two text view .but you keep same variable of both

Answer (score 5):

On my 4.1.2 device, `TextView` (it was actually an `AutoCompleteTextView`) did not want to accept `setVisibility(View.GONE)` because the box had **focus**. The problem was this was the last element on the screen, so I spent a while before I found an innocent target to shift the focus to. I had to use `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` for that other view, because otherwise its `requestFocus()` was silently ignored, as well as the TextView's `clearFocus()`.

Comment: quite right about not working View.GONE on 4.x, Im faced with the same. You've saved my day. But actually, I have no success with any focuses, and I had to wrap TextView in a layout to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

Also can happen (not this case) that the gone is ignored if the view is referenced by a group like this

```
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:constraint_referenced_ids="myTextView"
                tools:visibility="visible" />
```